# find integers connected with - in string php

Tags: php, string

So lets say I have an string like so.

```
$pizza = 1,2,3,5-4,7;
```

and what I want to get out of it is the 5-7 out of that set but that 5-7 could be any combo, say 6-9 or 10-1 and this occur multiple times.

Such as

```
$pizza=1-4,2,3-1,5-4,7;
```

So how would I go about that?

I understand how to get rid of the commas by explode and implode but then I don't know how to get the dashed numbers and the position of those numbers in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/(\d\-\d)/", $myString, $results);
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

You can "expand" ranges into their individual numbers with this:

```
$pizza = preg_replace_callback(
    "((\d+)-(\d+))",
    function($m) {
        return implode(",",range(min($m[1],$m[2]),max($m[1],$m[2])));
    },
    $pizza);
```

So for example if you put in `1,2,3,7-10,12`, the code will result in `1,2,3,7,8,9,10,12`. Then you can just put it in your already-known `explode` code and get the individual numbers.

I think this is what you're asking for.